# NPM command config is broken

Tags: node.js, npm

I edited `npm config set <key> <value>` and messed up.
Now whenever I try running anything that remotely starts with `npm config`, I'm getting an issue that looks like that:

> Error: Failed parsing JSON config key

How can I reset my `npm config` or find the file to manually delete my changes?

I have tried reinstalling npm and nvm several times.

## Accepted answer

Was technically correct, I also realized that I was missing a second question (ie how to find invisible files athe mac). I'm on a mac and .npmrc is a hidden file (which can be toggled with `cmd+shift+.`) But all in all, it worked out, thanks yall!

Comment: Duplicate with your same question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53936241/8828489

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM Error: failed parsing JSON config key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936241/npm-error-failed-parsing-json-config-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing the config file directly: ~/.npmrc

https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/customizing/the-npmrc-file.html

Comment: @SillyProgrammer, you should accept the answer if it solved your issue.